# Is it ok to have an instance of the implementation for ICommand interface in a self defined Exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, api, mvvm, delegates

I am writing an MVVM WPF application and I have to deal with `HttpResponseMessage` types when I call the API for content. The thing is, when the response's status type is not `Http 200 OK`, in the view-model I have to send a command to the view to display an acknowledge message. I do this thing by self defining an exception that holds an instance of a `Command<string>`, which is an implementation of `ICommand` interface. So, when i get a wrong response, i do the following:

```
if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var errorResponseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ShowMessage = new Command<string>(delegate (string s){ ShowErrorMessage(errorResponseMessage); });
                throw new InvalidResponseMessageException(ShowMessage);
            }
```

where ShowErrorMessage is defined like this:

```
private void ShowErrorMessage(string message)
        {
            MessageBoxService.ShowMessage(message, MessageType.Acknowledgment);
        }
```

and in the view, when i catch the Exception, i call the method: `ex.Command.Execute(null)`

Now, I was told that the Exception should not contain a definition of a delegate and that I should handle it with the help of another class, not from the Exception, because it is not serializable. But I don't quite know how should I send the command to display the error message from the view-model otherwise. Any suggestion would be helpful. thx

Comment: it is not ok to use exception for execution flow control in the first place

Comment: And how should I execute the command to display the message in the view only when the invalid response occurs in the view-model without breaking the mvvm pattern?

Comment: Like @ASh says, exceptions are EXCEPTIONAL (it means "must not occur, it's weird and i can't handle it"). Example "open file blabla.txt"---> "wow, this is weird, blabla.txt now doesn't exists, i break myself".

Comment: @LorenaDrăgan Do you want your app breaks if not http 200? Then Show the message and then break with exception. If the app must continue, doesn't throw the exception, only show the message. This second way is (IMHO) the best way. Break an app flow because of http error it's insane.

Comment: Something calls this to receive data. Then this part of your code does a http request and you want to communicate back to whatever called it if the http request failed. At the moment you're doing that by throwing an exception and in that exception attaching an action that should be taken. This seems like the wrong way around, whatever called this code should determine the action according to the response. We don't have much info to go on, but normally I would wrap this call in a generic response message (just like a http resonse) containing success info and requested data if available